# Does assertRaises work on builtin exceptions

Tags: python, unit-testing

- I have a function that wraps os remove.
- I have unit test setup as follows:

  self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError, my_rm(bad_file_path))

bad_file_path does not exist, so it throws exception. However, the above still fails testing. How could I test for FileNotFoundError, if possible?

Comment: The answer posted above is correct. Duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) recommends that you use `with` to run `assertRaises` tests, like this:

```
with self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError):
    my_rm(bad_file_path)
```

Otherwise, you would have to pass in the function and arguments separately, like this:

```
self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError, my_rm, bad_file_path)
```

What you're currently doing is calling `my_rm(bad_file_path)` and trying to pass the result of that call to `self.assertRaises()`. Since an exception occurs, the test crashes.